# Making a trig function that can be called in main

Tags: java, for-loop

I am working on making a function which can take arguments… `2^0 , 2^1 , 2^2, … 2^N` when given the variable `N`. This function must also be able to be called in main and given a command line argument. Any pointers? Here is what I have.

```
public static int PowersOfTwo(int N){
    for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++){
        int power = Math.pow(2, i);
        System.out.println(power);
    }
}
```

Comment: For me your code looks OK, but what is your question? Please ask it more precisely.

Comment: Firstly, java coding style is to name methods in camelCase. Also, you should think about naming methods using the verb-noun scheme (such as `printPowersOfTwo()` in this case).

Comment: Well the problem is that it keeps underlining Math.pow(2, i); and saying cannot convert from double to int… i don't know how to fix this

Comment: You need to explicitly cast from `double` to `int` as you lose precision. Try `int power = (int)Math.pow(2, i);`.

Comment: Okay that worked but I had to change the function to void, and now I don't know how to call it in main… heres what I put into main and it underlined the "z"'s.

Comment: double y = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);

Comment: System.out.println(z);

Comment: `PowersOfTwo()` doesn't return anything (it prints to the screen). You just need to call `PowersOfTwo(y)` in `main()`.

Comment: How do I do that? I have tried this...

Answer (score 1):

In the main you have an argument `String[] args` which is an array with all commands passed with command line.

Then you just need

```
if (args.length > 0) // check if the user launched the application with at least one command
 PowersOfTwo(Integer.parseInt(args[0])); // pass it to the function
```